# How stop call MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN & MotionEvent.ACTION_UP & MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE at same time?

Tags: java, android, touch, motionevent

I make a custom class of imageview and in that class has a onTouch method,
when i click on that view then face below issue

In My redmi device only call automatically when i touch view **MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN & MotionEvent.ACTION_UP** method at same time but in,

Other device call **MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN & MotionEvent.ACTION_UP & MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE** at same time ,

i want to call only **MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN & MotionEvent.ACTION_UP** that 2 mothod at same time

so i want to stop that 3 method call at same time is possible?

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Logger.e("call_:-  Dot touched");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Logger.e("call_:-  Dot moving + X: " + touchedDot.x + " Y: " +
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Logger.e("call_:-  Dot touched ACTION_UP");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
                mode = NONE;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Please consider better explaining what you problem is and what you would like to achieve.

Comment: i facing device specific issue , this onTouchMethod has a 3 override method and that 3 method call in some device at same time, but in some device call only 2 methods, so how to stop call that method at same time?